# Different results in using Augmented Dickey Fuller test in Python

Tags: python, statistics

I want to check whether data is stationary or not. I applied ADF test with different inputs for parameters as seen as below:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
Y = df.values
result = adfuller(Y, maxlag=15, autolag=None, regression='ct')
```

I got the first result:

```
adf              -16.057
p                1.12e-22
crit. val.       1%: -3.959, 5%: -3.411, 10%: -3.127
stationary?      true
```

The next one:

```
result = adfuller(Y) # use standard values for all parameters in adfuller() method
```

The result showed that my data is not stationary. It is opposite with the previous result:

```
ADF Statistic: -1.391000
p-value: 0.586583 
Critical Values:
        1%: -3.431
        5%: -2.862
        10%: -2.567
```

Should you help me explain why is it so different between both of results?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two reasons

1. Lags:

You set the `autolag=None` in your first test. With `autolag=None` The algorithm will use the maxlag as the lag in Augmented Dickey-Fuller test. So in `result = adfuller(Y, maxlag=15, autolag=None, regression='ct')`, it tests the stationary using data with 15 lags.

While default setting is `autolag = "AIC"` , it will chose the lag numbers to minimize the AIC. The chosen lag is in the 3rd of the test result `result[2]`.

So check whether the lag of two test is the same.

2. Regression:

   1). ‘ct’ : constant and trend

   2). default: constant only

The detail of adfuller in python: [adfuller](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.adfuller.html)

Answer (score 0):

In python I tried to use `adfuller(x, autolag = "AIC", regression='ct', maxlag=np.round((len(x) - 1) ** (1/3)))`
where `np.round((len(x) - 1) ** (1/3)))` is the `k` in `adf.test(x, k=trunc(length(x)-1)^(1/3))`